# Writing all bytes 0x00-0xFF to a file in Batch

Tags: batch-file

I'm trying to use batch to write all the bytes from 0x00 to 0xFF to a file. I've tried looking for this, and all I found was various workarounds for specific bytes (e.g. the CR character). I'm looking for something like

```
echo \x00\x1b\xff > file
```

resulting in `file` being 3 bytes long with the contents `001bff`.

Does this sort of thing exist in batch?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to (ab)use [certutil](https://ss64.com/nt/certutil.html):

```
(echo 00 1b ff)>file.hex
certutil -decodehex file.hex file.bin
```

Check [this](https://ss64.org/viewtopic.php?id=1562) and [this](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=5326) for more info

Comment: What versions of windows does `certutil` work on? I have it on my windows 7 machine, but I've found it's not on other machines.

Comment: @Daffy for XP and 2003 you need to install admin tools pack ( check on ss64 page) . On the newers widows machines it is installed by default.